# Minimum of a two-point discrete random variable and a constant

Tags: probability

X is a random variable that takes a value of a>=0 with probability 1/2 and b>=0 with probability 1/2. C is a non-negative constant. I am trying to calculate E[min(X,C)]. I find that the answer depends on the relationship between C and the boundary points a and b.

If $C<a$ ---> E[min(X,C)]=C

If $a<=C<b$ ----> E[min(X,C)]=(a+C)/2

If $C>=b$ ----> E[min(X,C)]=(a+b)/2

Can you please help me understand if I am making a mistake, and if so, how to correct it? Is it possible to write a single expression for E[min(X,C)], instead of specifying the answer within the regions $C<a$, $a<=C<b$, and $C>=b.$

Many thanks for feedback.

Comment: This looks right to me, and no, I can't see a way to write this in a single expression that is clearer than what you've already done (other than putting it in MathJax, but that's a formatting issue).

Comment: $(\min(a,C)+\min(b,C))/2$, maybe?

Comment: Thank you for the responses.